# Change GET var with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, get, var

Hello I searched everywhere for a solution to this but can't find the right answer, I hope some of you can help me.

I need to change this url:

`www.website.com/category/post?src=flash-game`

to this one:

`www.website.com/category/post?utm_source=www.referrer.com&utm_medium=swf_game_referral&utm_campaign=flash-game`

So basically I need to change the "`src`" var to "`utm_campaign`" and then get the "`utm_source`" with "`%{HTTP_REFERER}`" and manually add "`utm_medium`" with the value "`swf_game_referral`"

I tried using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} src=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ ?utm_source=%{HTTP_REFERER}&utm_medium=swf_game_referral&utm_campaign=%1 [QSA,R,L]
```

It works fine changing the GET var and adding all the other stuff but the problem is that it always redirects all the parameters to the home page, for example:

If someone goes to my website with this url:
`www.website.com/category/post?src=flash-game`

it will be redirected to:
`www.website.com/?utm_source=www.referrer.com&utm_medium=swf_game_referral&utm_campaign=flash-game`

and I need it to stay in the original path:
`www.website.com/category/post?utm_source=www.referrer.com&utm_medium=swf_game_referral&utm_campaign=flash-game`

Comment: Hello Crash, welcome to StackOverflow.
Would you mind formatting your question so that it's a bit more readable?
That would allow us to help you better

Comment: Hello Timothy, I'm sorry didn't find a specific formatting option for htaccess code, it wont happen again! thanks for the advice

Comment: No sweat. 
The formatting code is always the same, Stackoverflow does its best to figure out the most appropriate formatting, but it always makes it easier for us to read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the URI as part of the target, so that your `RewriteRule` line looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?utm_source=%{HTTP_REFERER}&utm_medium=swf_game_referral&utm_campaign=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Jon, but your answer makes an endless look giving a server error. I need to change the "src" parameter only

Comment: @CrashOverride Oh, you need to drop the `QSA` flag, since the condition is that you need the `src=` param, but `QSA` appends it after the rewrite, causing it to loop.

Comment: thanks again Jon Lin, I removed the QSA flag but the loop didn't disappear :/